# How to make different types of relationship in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

To give some context I need help making a database on the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio based on an ERD, I'm currently struggling on how to make different types of relationships between each table.

The relationships I have aren't what I need, and I can't change them to be mandatory one to many, etc.

[My database of diagram of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enPim.png)

[The ERD I'm using to make the database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfpXX.png)

Every time I add the tables to the database diagram it gives me that type of relationship when I know I know I need different relationships instead, so overall I need help making the relationships in the database diagram match the ERD image.

Sidenote: I can't code the tables I have to use the database diagrams tool to make the tables the relationship.

Comment: I would not use the database diagram tool to create tables (and the relationships between them). You should write scripts (code) to do this. Yes, it takes more time and effort, but it gives you complete control over what your produce, AND lets you you access all possible design features and options.

Answer (score 0):

What type of relationships are you needing?

Generally in SQL Server you can utilize Primary Key and Foreign Key relationships. I would consider scaling based on how the tables will be loaded and storage when designing.

Try adding an Employee-FK to the Computer object and a Computer-FK to the Software Package object.

Comment: I need relationships like optional many to many, mandatory one to many, and mandatory one to optional one.